# Programmatic connection to third party database using "runas"?

Tags: python, ssms, pyodbc, pymssql, runas

My work laptop is connected in the corporate network of company A, and my user account is "A/username". I have been provisioned access in the network of company B, with a user account "B/username", to access their databases.

We use Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio, and the "trick" is to execute a command to run this as an alias:

```
C:\Windows\System32\runas.exe /netonly /user:**user@company_B.com** "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 18\Common7\IDE\Ssms.exe"
```

This leads to the popup of a prompt for me to enter my password for my company B account, and then the UI for MS SQL Server Management Studio starts.

On this, if I click on Connect > Database Engine, the only thing I need to add the server (host) of the company B DB: "sql-server.company_b.com", and I can access the databases/tables, even though the authentication method (Windows Authentication) has a grayed out username for company A - this is circumvented by the `runas` part in the alias.

Is there a way to emulate this whole behavior programmatically (preferably in Python) with `pyodbc` or `pymssql`? I have been trying to populate the `URL.connection_string` using `sqlalchemy` but I always get an error of authentication when I try to connect to the company B's server without using the alias to SSMS.exe ...